# Get the version of the package been replaced in Android

Tags: android

I have a Broadcast receiver registered to be notified when PACKAGE_REPLACED intent is sent.
In the onReceiver I need to perform some operations on the basis of the version of the package been replaced. 
Is there a way to get that information? I tried:

```
Uri data = intent.getData();
final String intentPackageName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
pi = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(intentPackageName , PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
versionCode = pi.versionCode;
versionName = pi.versionName;
packageName = pi.packageName;
```

It does not work because the version is already replaced and what I get is the new and not the old one.

Comment: You can store the version somewhere (e.g. in SharedPreferences). And than read it when the package is replaced. Of course you should guarantee that the version in SharedPreferences remains actual.

Comment: the problem is that the old version don't have this number. Anyway yes I know that there are ways to work around the problem but I was wondering whether there is a proper way to read that info

Comment: Oh, i see. Haven't thought about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked in the sources of Gingerbread version. I guess that this is impossible to check. Previous version of the application is not stored. I do not know why. You can create a feature request to Google to add this feature.